# Flask route passing with parameter returning error

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to Flask. I have a problem with my code. I want my app to delete a specified file in my directory.

First, this is my code for showing all file in a specified directory in the form of a list:

```
@app.route('/dirfile')
   def dirfile():
       path = './static/pickle/'
       lst = os.listdir(path)
       return render_template('dirfile.html', lst=lst)
```

Here's my dirfile.html code showing all files in directory.

```
 {% for file_name in lst %}
    <ul class="list-group ">
      <li class="list-group-item ">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            {{ file_name }}
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <a
              href="{{ url_for('deldir/{{file_name}}') }}"
              class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right"
              >Delete</a
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  {% endfor %}
```

If you notice, I added a delete button to perform deletion in a specified file in the list.

My delete function:

```
@app.route('/deldir/<string:file_name>')
   def deldir(file_name):
       path = './static/pickle/'
       base = file_name
       fullpath = path + base
       os.remove(fullpath)
       return redirect(url_for('dirfile'))
```

But it returned the following error:

> werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'deldir/{{file_name}}'. Did you mean 'dirfile' instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url_for()` needs name of function, not url in `route()`.

Your function has name `deldir` and it has parameter with name `file_name` so you have

```
 url_for('deldir', file_name=file_name)
```

Comment: thank, it solved my problem. just know url_for can pass paramater too